# Reset some input in a Form

Tags: jquery

How I need to RESET a form without touching "hidden" input and "submit", I tried the follow but doesn't works,

```
$("#myForm textarea input[type!='submit'] input[type!='hidden']").val('');
```

How can I do it using Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myForm :input:not(:hidden):not(:submit)").val('');
```

Note that `:hidden` also selects hidden elements - if you want only `type="hidden"` form elements but not e.g. a hidden `type="text"` element, use `[type="hidden"]` instead.

Or maybe you simply want to do `$('#myForm')[0].reset();`

Comment: Doesn't work as `input[type!='submit']` returns hidden fields and `input[type!='hidden']` returns submits

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to select all input fields and then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out what you don't want and reset the ones you are left with.

```
$("#myForm :input").filter(function() { 
    return !($(this).is(':submit') || $(this).attr('type') == 'hidden');
}).val('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/rpRqX/

Alternative without using filter:

```
$("#myForm :input").not(':submit').not('[type="hidden"]').val('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/rpRqX/1/